# MAMP downloads file when trying to access PHPMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, macos, phpmyadmin, mamp

I have just installed MAMP and I'm trying to access PHPMyAdmin by going to `http://localhost:3306/MAMP`. This will just start downloading a file called MAMP with the following content:

```
J
5.5.42
`q6X9T{1ˇ˜Ä~H.KolO)zP_jmysql_native_password!ˇÑ#08S01Got packets out of order
```

If I change to `..:3306/PHPMyAdmin` it just downloads a file with `PHPMyAdmin` as a title and similar content.

I have changed the MySQL-port to 3306 (and the Apache port to 80) because I'm using VirtualHostX for adding virtual hosts.

I can see in my MAMP-window that MySQL Server is running (the box is green) but Apache Server is not. What am I doing wrong? How do I get Apache Server to run?

Answer (score 0):

By going into the terminal and entering `sudo apachectl stop` I stopped Apache and could start it up from the MAMP-window without any trouble.